# Sql use smaller than like from-in to-in command

Tags: mysql, sql

You suppose in posts table i have 10 record with `deleted` column on that, for example:

```
id    title     deleted
1     a         true
2     a         true
3     a         false
4     a         false
5     a         false
6     a         false
7     a         false
8     a         false
9     a         true
10    a         true
```

`deleted` column from `id` 3 to 8 are `false`

i want to select all records between from 3 until `deleted` column is `true` to find count of records which in this between are `false`,

for example

```
select * from posts where id = 10 (to find which id is true)
```

i want to have this result :

```
3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the first `id` (>3) which is deleted you can use:

```
SELECT id FROM posts WHERE deleted = 'true' AND id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Which will result in `9`. Use above as a subquery, to find all rows between 3 and 8:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE id >= 3 
  AND id < (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE deleted = 'true' AND id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
```

The subquery will return `NULL` if there aren't any `deleted = 'true'` rows after `id > 3`, so to add that case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE id >= 3 
  AND (
    id < (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE deleted = 'true' AND id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
    OR (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE deleted = 'true' AND id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) IS NULL
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, how about `9` and `10` are `false` ? for example `AND id < (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE deleted = 'true'  || deleted = 'false' AND id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)` may be all records from 3 to end are false

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy I've added that situation to my answer, Honestly I don't know whether MySQL is smart enough to execute that subquery only once, so there might be a more resource-efficient query.

Comment: unfortunately i have a problem, your command in this screen shot return only one row as id `2` http://rupload.ir/upload/s4r1lnk17r0stjq9tacw.png

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: `2,3,4,5` find from 2 to which id is `0` if `6` is `0` or  to 5 if 5 is `1`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `WHERE is_delete = 0` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151796/discussion-between-mahdi-pishguy-and-peter-van-der-wal).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method that finds the next true id in a subquery in the `from` clause:

```
select count(*), group_concat(id) as listIds
from posts p cross join
     (select min(p.id) as minid
      from posts p
      where p.id > 3 and p.deleted = true
     ) pp
where p.id > 3 and (p.id < pp.minid or pp.minid is null);
```

This will count all subsequent ids, even when no laters one are true.  This returns both the count and the list of ids.

Comment: unfortunately i get `zero`

Comment: `group_concat(ids)` should be `group_concat(id)` (singular)